# error when seeding data into a database in laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8, factory, laravel-seeding

am getting this error when seeding data into my database. apparently the I have 2 models bookings and bookingstatus model.the bookingstatus seeder is working well and is seeding the status very well but when it comes to the bookings the data is unable to seed.this is the error that pops up

```
ErrorException 

  Undefined variable:

  at F:\Main Server\htdocs\voskillproject\database\seeders\BookingsSeeder.php:73
     69▕             'event_details'=>'we would like to book you for a wedding'
     70▕
     71▕         ]);
     72▕         $Approved->bookingstatus()->attach($Approvedstatus);
  ➜  73▕         $Cancelled->bookingstatus()->attach($$Cancelledstatus);
     74▕         $DepositPaid->bookingstatus()->attach($DepositPaidstatus);
     75▕         $Published->bookingstatus()->attach($Publishedstatus);
     76▕     }
     77▕ }

  1   F:\Main Server\htdocs\voskillproject\database\seeders\BookingsSeeder.php:73
      Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError("Undefined variable: ", "F:\Main Server\htdocs\voskillproject\database\seeders\BookingsSeeder.php")

  2   F:\Main Server\htdocs\voskillproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:36
      Database\Seeders\BookingsSeeder::run()
```

this is my BookingsFactory

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Bookings;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class BookingsFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Bookings::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'is_booking'=>0,
            'full_name'=>$this->faker->unique()->name,
            'location'=>$this->faker->location,
            'phone'=>$this->faker->number,
            'is_booking'=>3,
            'email'=>$this->faker->safeEmail,
            'date'=>$this->faker->date,
            'event_id'=>$this->faker->event_id,
            'event_details'=>$this->faker->paragraph,
            
        ];
    }
}
```

this is my database seeder

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\Bookingstatus;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Database\Seeders\RoleSeeder;
use Database\Seeders\Userseeder;
use Database\Seeders\BookingsSeeder;
use Database\Seeders\BookingstatusSeeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call([
            BookingsSeeder::class,
            BookingstatusSeeder::class,
        ]);
        \App\Models\Bookingstatus::factory()->hasbookings(10)->create();

        
    }
}
```

i have not understood where ie gone wrong in the code

Answer (score 0):

i figure out where the issue was
1.first on the bookings factory i have to change the faker details to this

```
return [
            'is_booking'=>0,
            'full_name'=>$this->faker->unique()->name,
            'location'=>$this->faker->address,
            'phone'=>$this->faker->numerify('###-###-####'),
            'is_booking'=>3,
            'email'=>$this->faker->safeEmail,
            'date'=>$this->faker->unique()->dateTime()->format('Y/m/d'),
            'event_id'=>$this->faker->randomDigit(),
            'event_details'=>$this->faker->paragraphs(2, true),
            
        ];
```

also i should have imported this code at the top of the bookingstatus factory

use Illuminate\Support\Str;